# Call to undefined method stdClass::onDisplay() error

Tags: php, joomla2.5, stdclass

I have a joomla 2.5 installation. I just installed community builder component. when I tried to add a field, I got the error message:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::onDisplay() in /home/sharpfoc/public_html/joomla16/libraries/joomla/html/editor.php on line 459
if anybody has a clue on how to solve this issue, it will be appreciated. thanks.
souleye

Comment: what are we supposed to tell you now other than what the error message already told you? You have a [generic object](http://de.php.net/manual/de/language.types.object.php) and try to call a method on it that it doesnt have. So pull out your debugger and step through your code to find out what's happening. In order to make a qualified guess, we'd at least need to see line 459 and some surrounding/calling code.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the file “editor.php” in the folder libraries/joomla/html

Replaced the line

```
  $resultTest = $plugin->onDisplay($editor);
```

which is in line 261* after the line

```
// Try to authenticate — only add to array if authentication is successful
```

to

```
 if (method_exists($plugin, 'onDisplay')) {
     $result[] = $plugin->onDisplay($editor);
 }
```

It worked for me. Hope it will work for you too

Comment: only fixes symptoms and not the root cause but I guess it's useful, so +1

Comment: the offending line of code is: // Try to authenticate
   if ($temp = $plugin->onDisplay($editor, $this->asset, $this->author))
   {
    $result[] = $temp;
   }

Comment: Looks like some plugin did not load.

Comment: Change line 268 of /libraries/joomla/html/editor.php from:

`$resultTest = $plugin->onDisplay($editor);`

To:

`// $resultTest = $plugin->onDisplay($editor);

if (method_exists($plugin, 'onDisplay')) {
     $result[] = $plugin->onDisplay($editor);
     if ($resultTest) $result[] =  $resultTest;
}
else{
    $resultTest = false;
    echo '<h4>Bad Plugin: '.$plugin->name.'</h4>';
}`

This will get rid of the error, and also show you what plugin is not properly installed so you can reinstall it (in my case it was "Modules Anywhere").

Comment: This issue is definitely related to some editor plugin missing the 'onDisplay' method. So you should check all of your `editor-xtd` type plugins. A cause of such issue in plugin could be that the plugins are outdated, so updating the plugins could fix this issue.